# Get the width (in px) of a div sized by height (in %)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that is sized by height, its width is empty.

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow {
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
}
```

I need to get its current width in px in order to place other elements on the page. I tried the following but since the CSS has no width, the value of the var is 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var divWidth = $('#slideshow').width();
});
```

**UPDATE**
I found the issue, the child img loads with a programmed delay, so obviously the var gets an initial value of 0. Is there a way to get the width of the div with a delay?

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/RtLJq/.

Comment: Like null proved you, i don't see any reason for that code to fail, unless you have more that one div with that id and no image inside, check the rest of your code, because as it is it works.

Comment: A quick workaround would be to use jQuery's load method? somethin glike this: ```$("#slideshow img").load(function() { /*do div width here?*/ })```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to wait until the window is fully loaded. I added a setTimeout for you as well since you asked for it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var divWidth = $('#slideshow').width();
        // put your function using divWidth in here as well.
    }, 500);
});
```